How to achieve full viewport height without scrollbars using PrimeNG, PrimeFlex, and h-screen?
I'm building an interface using Angular along with PrimeNG and PrimeFlex. I want a container to fill the entire height of the screen without any scroll bars appearing. I've tried using both h-screen and h-full classes, but the element extends beyond the viewport height, causing scrollbars to appear.
What I've tried:

Replacing h-screen with h-full.
Ensuring there are no external margins or paddings causing the overflow.

GitHub Repository:
To assist in troubleshooting, I have made a minimal reproducible example available on GitHub. You can clone the repository, install dependencies, and run the project using the following commands:
git clone https://github.com/kashif-khan/PrimeNgAngular.git
cd PrimeNgAngular
npm install
npm start


Here's a simplified version of my code:
<div class="">
  <div class="m-5 p-5 text-5xl text-center">This is navbar</div>

  <p-splitter [panelSizes]="[20, 60, 20]" styleClass="m-0 p-0 h-screen">
    <ng-template pTemplate>
      <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-red-400 text-5xl text-white">
        Panel 1
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate>
      <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-green-400 text-5xl text-white">
        <p-card header="Car header" subheader="Card Subheader" styleClass="w-full">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <div class="flex flex-row-reverse flex-wrap">
              <p-button label="Float right" styleClass="m-2" />
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ul>
            <li>Ensure that this card occupies the entire height and width of the green panel.</li>
          </ul>
          <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
            <div class="flex flex-row mt-1">
              <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                <p-button label="Float left" severity="secondary" />
              </div>
              <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                <p-button label="Float right" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </p-card>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate>
      <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-blue-400 text-5xl text-white">
        Panel 3
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-splitter>
</div>


You need a vertical p-splitter, followed by the horizontal splitter, this will give you the desired result.
<p-splitter 
    [panelSizes]="[20, 80]" styleClass="m-0 p-0 h-screen"
    layout="vertical">
        <ng-template pTemplate>
            <div class="h-100  w-100 flex align-items-center justify-content-center">This is navbar</div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate>
            <p-splitter [panelSizes]="[20, 60, 20]" styleClass="m-0 p-0">
                <ng-template pTemplate>
                <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-red-400 text-5xl text-white">
                    Panel 1
                </div>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate>
                <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-green-400 text-5xl text-white">
                    <p-card header="Car header" subheader="Card Subheader" styleClass="w-full">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                        <div class="flex flex-row-reverse flex-wrap">
                        <p-button label="Float right" styleClass="m-2" />
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ensure that this card occupies the entire height and width of the green panel.</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
                        <div class="flex flex-row mt-1">
                        <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                            <p-button label="Float left" severity="secondary" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                            <p-button label="Float right" />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                    </p-card>
                </div>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate>
                <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-blue-400 text-5xl text-white">
                    Panel 3
                </div>
                </ng-template>
            </p-splitter>
        </ng-template>
</p-splitter>

